# Cant get the table column in the .xls file

Tags: php, mysqli, xls

I have a page that allow user to export particular data in .xls file.

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$user_name=$_SESSION['name'];$sql = "select * from asset_details inner join bank_details on asset_details.user_id=bank_details.user_id  inner join merchant_details on asset_details.user_id=merchant_details.user_id inner join merchant_status on asset_details.user_id=merchant_status.user_id inner join merchant_ids on asset_details.user_id=merchant_ids.user_id  inner join terminal_details on asset_details.user_id=terminal_details.user_id where asset_details.user_id='$user_name' order by merchant_details.time_date asc" ;       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql); function filterData(&$str)
{
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// file name for download
$fileName = "report" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

// headers for download
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;
foreach($result as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
        // display column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    // filter data
    array_walk($row, 'filterData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
}

exit;}
```

The Problem is that while exporting the data it takes column name from database rather than from the column name on the page.